# Scala conditional None value assignment

Tags: scala

I am trying to convert com.google.gson.JsonObject to case class object. Sometime some element in the record are missing in which case I want it to be assigned as None to case class member

```
object tmp {
  case class person(name: String, age: Long)
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
   val parser = new JsonParser();

   //PERSON 2
   val record2 = parser.parse("""{"name":"xyz"}""").getAsJsonObject()

   val record2_name = record2.get("name").getAsString.toLowerCase
   val record2_age = if(record2.get("age") != null) record2.get("age") else None

   val person2 = new person(record2_name,record2_age)  //-> Type Mismatch, expected: Long, actual: Long

   println(person2);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `record2_age` is of type `JsonElement` which is simply of type java `Object`, but since you are assigning `None` to it, it becomes `Any` WHICH you are trying to assign to type `Long`.

Short answer would be ,

```
val person = new person(jsonObject.get("name").getAsString.toLowerCase,
    Option(jsonObject.get("age")).map(_.getAsLong).getOrElse(0l))
```

This way if `jsonObject.get("age")` is null, `Option(null)` gives you `None`, or if present you get `Option(28)` = `Some(28)`

You probably want your age to be `0l` if empty. If you want it to be `None`, then you can use `Option[Long]`.

**1) simpler way**

```
class GsonCaseClassSpecs extends FunSpec {

  describe("case class conversion") {

    it("converts gson with name/age to case class") {

      case class person(name: String, age: Long)

      val parser = new JsonParser()

      //case 1
      val jsonObject : JsonObject = parser.parse("""{"name":"xyz"}""").getAsJsonObject

      val age = jsonObject.get("age") match {
        case null => None
        case value => Some(value.getAsLong)
      }

      val person1 = new person(jsonObject.get("name").getAsString.toLowerCase, age.getOrElse(0l))

      assert(person1.name == "xyz")
      assert(person1.age == 0)

      //case 2
      val jsonObject2 : JsonObject = parser.parse("""{"name":"xyz", "age" : 28}""").getAsJsonObject

      val age2 : Option[Long] = jsonObject2.get("age") match {
        case null => None
        case value => Some(value.getAsLong)
      }

      val person2 = new person(jsonObject2.get("name").getAsString.toLowerCase, age2.getOrElse(0l))

      assert(person2.name == "xyz")
      assert(person2.age == 28)
    }

  }
}
```

**2) If you want to make the age to be `Option[Long]`.** `Option[T]` can have `Some(x)` or `None`.

```
class CaseClassFunSpecs extends FunSpec {

 it("converts json to case class with empty age"){

  case class person(name: String, age: Option[Long])

  val parser = new JsonParser()

  val json = parser.parse("""{"name":"xyz"}""").getAsJsonObject()

  val personInstance = new person(json.get("name").getAsString.toLowerCase,
    Option(json.get("age")).map(_.getAsLong))

  assert(personInstance.name == "xyz")
  assert(personInstance.age == None)
  // NOTE
  // do not do personInstance.age.get which would throw
  // None.get
  // java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
  // at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
  // at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)

  //rather use pattern match
  personInstance.age match {
    case Some(x) => println("value = " + x)
    case None => throw new RuntimeException("Age can not be empty.")
  }
  }

 it("converts json to case class with non-empty age"){

  case class person(name: String, age: Option[Long])

  val parser = new JsonParser()

  val json = parser.parse("""{"name":"xyz", "age" : 28}""").getAsJsonObject()

  val personInstance = new person(json.get("name").getAsString.toLowerCase,
    Option(json.get("age")).map(_.getAsLong))

  assert(personInstance.name == "xyz")
  assert(personInstance.age == Some(28))
  assert(personInstance.age.get == 28) //.get gives you the value 
 }
}
```

Comment: This is setting age as 0 which could be. I need something to indicate this element was missing from the row.

Comment: @xstack2000 If thats the case, then you need `Option[Long]`. See the updated answer. Let me know if that helps

Comment: @xstack2000 also read NOTE while using `ageOption`, as `.get` on `None` will throw exception, rather use pattern matching as described above.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't call a parameter of one type, `age: Long` in your case, with an argument of a different type `Option[Long]`.

At least this is what your question seems to imply.

You need to define the attributes that could be missing as `Option`s.

e.g. in your example

```
case class person(name: String, age: Option[Long])
```

and then when you extract the json value you can make use of the `Option.apply` method, that returns `None` if the argument is `null`

```
…
val record2_age = Option(record2.get("age")).map(_.getAsLong) // None if get("age) returns null
…
val person2 = new person(record2_name,record2_age)  //There should be no more type mismatch now
```

Comment: I did try Option but it still doesnt work                                    

val person2 = new person(record2_name, record2_age) 
//-> Type Mismatch, expected: Option[Long], actual: Option[jsonElement]

Comment: Updated the answer as in @prayagupd's answer, try now